# Multi dimensional array with double and int

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is what i got so far

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

  int[]aryNumbers = new int[20];

  double[]aryNumbers2 = new double [2];

  aryNumbers[0] = 10;
  aryNumbers[1] = 20;
  aryNumbers[2] = 30;
  aryNumbers[3] = 40;
  aryNumbers[4] = 50;

  aryNumbers2[2] = 6.2;
  aryNumbers2[2] = 6.3;
  aryNumbers2[2] = 6.4;
  aryNumbers2[2] = 6.5;
  aryNumbers2[2] = 6.6;

  int rows = 20;
  double columns = 2;
  int i;
  double j;


  for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {

      for(j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
          System.out.print( aryNumbers[i] + " " );
          System.out.print( aryNumbers2[j] + " " ); 

      }
      System.out.println( "" );

  }
```

The program is supposed to list up like this

KM   =    Miles
10        6.2
15        9.3
20        12.4

showing what Km is in miles up till 100 km.
Any help is greatly appreciated been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: You're filling the same array item for the aryNumbers2 array as each number goes into the 3rd array item kicking out the previous item -- not very useful. Have you gone through the most basic array tutorials yet? Also, there are no multidimensional arrays in your code. Don't guess -- start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: and you set value for second array outside its bound (it has only 2 elements but you refer to arr[2])

Comment: A first hint would be: start with the naming of your arrays. Dont repeat the type "aryNumber" --- you know that you want an array of numbers. Instead, specify what the array should be used for. For example, you might want to call your two arrays "distancesInKm" and "distancesInMiles". That might also make it much clearer to you how to **use** this arrays; and which values to put in. And further on: right now, you do not have a two-dimenstional array. You have to single-dim arrays - that is not the same!

Comment: why assigning aryNumbers[2] so many times? all you are doing is replacing the previous assignment

Comment: And you should start learning to use a die debugger. This is very helpful and easy to do with this small program. Happy learning :).

Comment: Btw you don't have a multi dimensional array, so you don't need the second 'for' loop. Just use 'i' to access items from 'aryNumbers2'.

Comment: Not related to the question, but there's a method `println()` with no parameters in `System.out`. Would be better than `println("")`.

Answer (score 1):

This code generates your expected output:

```
package stackoverflowtmp;

public class StackoverflowTmp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] kilometers = new int[3];
        double[] miles = new double[3];

        kilometers[0] = 10;
        kilometers[1] = 15;
        kilometers[2] = 20;

        miles[0] = 6.2;
        miles[1] = 9.3;
        miles[2] = 12.4;

        System.out.print("KM = Miles ");
        for (int i=0; i < kilometers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(kilometers[i] + " ");
            System.out.print(miles[i] + " "); 
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:
`KM = Miles 10 6.2 15 9.3 20 12.4`

---

However, I would suggest you to create a function to calculate the number of miles for a given number of kilometers according to `km = 1.609344*miles` or vice versa `miles = 0.621371192*km` instead of using predefined values.

Example code for that:

```
package stackoverflowtmp;

public class StackoverflowTmp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("KM => Miles: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i += 10) {
            System.out.print(i + " => " + kmToMiles((double)i) + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static double kmToMiles(double km) {
        return km * 0.621371192;
    }
}
```

Outputs:
`KM => Miles: 0 => 0.0, 10 => 6.21371192, 20 => 12.42742384, 30 => 18.64113576, 40 => 24.85484768,`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have no multi dimensional array in your code right now.

What you could use is simply a single array called miles. You insert in this array the values of the miles and you compare it to the index of the array. Make sure you understand the difference between the element contained in the array and it's index value.

As an exemple if you use the formula for km to miles conversion; `mi = km * 0.62137` you could easily fill an array go get what you need.

The following code should achieve this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    double[] miles = new double[101];

    for (int i = 0; i < miles.length ; i++) {
        miles[i] = i * 0.62137;

        System.out.println(i + " km = " + miles[i] + " miles");
    }
}
```

Note that I use the double primitive for the array since it will be much more precise using floating points than integers where you would loose precision. But if you want to round before the comma, change the array declaration to int[].

Note2: Whan you declare an array, the number 101 represents the numbers of index (length of array) that you want to create. Then you are able to loop over `miles.length` in order to fill those empty spots.

**Edit**

If you only need one number after the comma for the miles value use this line instead in your for loop: `miles[i] = Math.floor((i * 0.62137) * 10) / 10;`

And would give you the output of:

```
0 km = 0.0 miles
1 km = 0.6 miles
2 km = 1.2 miles
3 km = 1.8 miles
4 km = 2.4 miles
5 km = 3.1 miles
6 km = 3.7 miles
7 km = 4.3 miles
8 km = 4.9 miles
9 km = 5.5 miles
10 km = 6.2 miles
...
```

Hope this helps